# Chrome on Android cannot post salary calculator form

Tags: bug, salary-calculator

I see only red check boxes when clicking submit button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Repros while incognito.

Comment: Does the error still persist when you narrow down the amount of checked boxes under technologies to 5? (As the form says you can add up to 5 technologies)

Comment: As Codeer mentioned, this is expected when you choose more than 5 tags. I totally see how we could add a text message there though. Does it happen with 5 tags or less?

Comment: It works as expected when I follow the instructions. :)

I saw the hint, "Optional, add up to 5", and frankly did not bother processing "add up to 5" when it seemed like the text was there to let me know I did not need to fill any boxes.

Comment: This really needs an accompanying error message.